# Recursively searching the registry

Tags: windows, recursion, registry, inno-setup

I can successfully query for a known Key's value, using the code below. How can I recursively search the subkeys (in my example below, all subkeys within the Uninstall folder) for a particular data's value? My aim is to see if some particular program is installed, and if not, install it.

```
function
...(omitted)
var
     Res : String;
     begin
      RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{92EA4162-10D1-418A-91E1-5A0453131A38}','DisplayName', Res);
      if Res <> 'A Value' then
        begin
        // Successfully read the value
        MsgBox('Success: ' + Res, mbInformation, MB_OK);
        end
    end;
```

Comment: Tlama has given you an answer, but applications normally use fixed IDs, maybe changing at a major version upgrade. There should be no need to enumerate them to find a single application.

Comment: That's a good point and it's a question I still had. I noticed that the application I was looking for had the same GUID across multiple machines & installs, but because I didn't completely understand *how* applications get labeled in the Registry I opted for a future-proof but computationally-expensive route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The principle is easy, with the [`RegGetSubkeyNames`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_reggetsubkeynames.htm) you'll get an array of subkeys of a certain key and then you just iterate this array and query all the subkeys for the `DisplayName` value and compare the value (if any) with the searched one.

The following function shows the implementation. Note, that I've removed the `Wow6432Node` node from the path, so if you really need it, modify the `UnistallKey` constant in the code:

```
[Code]
const
  UnistallKey = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall';

function IsAppInstalled(const DisplayName: string): Boolean;
var
  S: string;
  I: Integer;
  SubKeys: TArrayOfString;
begin
  Result := False;

  if RegGetSubkeyNames(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, UnistallKey, SubKeys) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(SubKeys) - 1 do
    begin
      if RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, UnistallKey + '\' + SubKeys[I],
        'DisplayName', S) and (S = DisplayName) then
      begin
        Result := True;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else
    RaiseException('Opening the uninstall key failed!');
end;
```